# регулярные выражения javascript replace

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пример

```
let text = 'Шла саша по шоссе и сосала сушку';
```

как заменить 'саша по шоссе', на 'Маша по дороге', но не просто методом

```
text = text.replace('саша по шоссе', 'Маша по дороге')
```

а что бы в функции было обозначено начало 'Шла' и конец 'сосала'.  (я не специально=). 
Другими словами: мне нужна замена от конкретного начала и конца текста. а то что находится в середине текста не имело значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
let text = 'Шла саша по шоссе и сосала сушку';
text = text.replace(
    /(^Шла ).*( и сосала сушку$)/, 
    '$1Маша по дороге$2'
);
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Судя по вопросу, автору скорее нужна такая регулярка: `/(Шла )(.*)( и сосала сушку)/`

Comment: @Yaant Ага, обновил